# Strange partial refresh of embedded Excel chart in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, excel-charts

I have a Word template with linked, embedded Excel charts. When I create a document from the template, I refresh the charts, first like this in Excel, updating not only data point values but also what data points (what rows of data) are included:

```
ThisWorkbook.Charts("My Chart").SetSourceData Source:=rgBuilder
```

Then I update the embedded charts in the document created from the Word template like this:

```
For Each oEmbeddedExcelChart In oDoc.InlineShapes
   oEmbeddedExcelChart.LinkFormat.Update: DoEvents
   oEmbeddedExcelChart.LinkFormat.BreakLink
Next oEmbeddedExcelChart
```

One of the charts refreshes fine. But another one refreshes only data points, without refreshing changes to what data points (what rows in the data) are included. Depending on the data in any particular run, that sometimes has the bizarre effect of making the chart look in Word like it never looked in Excel.

I tried switching positions of the charts in the Word template, and the problem stayed with the same chart. I tried deleting and recreating the chart, but the new one had the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `DoEvents` only yields to events that are currently queued. Looks like a timing issue with the ActiveX server.

Comment: @Comintern, thanks, but the same problem happens when I step through and examine the results after each line. But I'll test whether Wait or Sleep help.

Comment: @Comintern, I see now that the same problem happens when I refresh manually, not running any code at all. Hmm....